# Continuously re-running a while loop until a certain input

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do with this is ask the user for two inputs and then call a function on the inputs. If it doesn't raise an exception then do the while loop again. If it does raise an exception than print something and do the while loop again. The problem I have is that I can't find a way to do the while loop again if it doesn't raise an exception. It works if it does raise an exception. The only way I can think of it is where I put #Rerun loop paste the entire while True loop again but that would be really horrible in this case.

```
class Illegal(Exception):
    pass

def add_input(first_input, second_input):
    if first_input + second_input >= 10:
        print('legal')
    else:
        raise Illegal

def play():
    inp = input("Ready? <yes/no>: ")
    if inp == 'yes':
        while True:
            first_input = input("First number: ")
            second_input = input("Second number: ")
            try:
                if first_input or second_input == 'quit':
                     break
                else:
                     add_input(int(first_input), int(second_input))
                     #Rerun loop
            except Illegal:
                print("Illegal")
            else:
                break
    else:
        return

   >>> play()
       Ready? <yes/no>: yes
       First number: 1
       Second number: 2
       Illegal
       First number: 9
       Second number: 6
       legal
       First number: 1
       Second number: 2
       Illegal
       First number: quit
```

What I thought of doing:

```
def play():
    inp = input("Ready? <yes/no>: ")
    if inp == 'yes':
        while True:
            first_input = input("First number: ")
            second_input = input("Second number: ")
            try:
                if first_input or second_input == 'quit':
                    break
                else:
                    add_input(int(first_input), int(second_input))
                    while True:
                            first_input = input("First number: ")
                           except Illegal:
                                print("Illegal move")
                            else:
                                break
            except Illegal:
                print("Illegal move")
            else:
                break
    else:
        return                     second_input = input("Second number: ")
                            try:
                                if first_input or second_input == 'quit':
                                    break
                                else:
                                    add_input(int(first_input), int(second_input))
                                    #Rerun loop
```

But this is a horrible idea because then I'd have to paste the same thing continuously.

Comment: @warunsl The question is slightly different since the author has made some progress in his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` in your `else:` causes the loop to exit. You can remove this entirely:

```
else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to run the loop while the user doesn't quit it via typing `quit`. So you just have to remove this `else: break`:

```
def play():
    inp = input("Ready? <yes/no>: ")
    if inp.lower() == 'yes':
        while True:
            first_input = input("First number: ")
            second_input = input("Second number: ")
            # quit if the user wants
            if first_input or second_input == 'quit':
                break

            try:
                add_input(int(first_input), int(second_input))
            except Illegal:
                print("Illegal")
```

Also, take the habit to put the minimum of code in your `try/except` blocks. It makes the debugging easier after. Your last `else: return` is also useless, you can remove it.